# How to do something before applicationDidFinishLaunching

Tags: iphone

Apple allow us to define our own Logo image from simulator launch to execute applicationDidFinishLaunching end. 
Now I want to do something between Logo on screen to IPHONE display the first view. I don't know how to do this. 
Thanks everybody who help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your AppDelegate class, just insert the code you want before `[window makeKeyAndVisible];` in the `applicationDidFinishLaunching:` method.