# How to do something as application load Logo image

Tags: iphone

I want to do something as apple load Logo image(Default.png). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You just asked pretty much the same question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1919939/how-to-do-something-before-applicationdidfinishlaunching

Comment: Yes, there is: put the phone down and go do something while your app is loading. When it's finished, come back to it.

Answer (score 1):

no, your app is loading.